# why range(start, stop, step) don't work?

Tags: python, arguments, range

I have python 3 and when I use the function like this:
range(start, stop, step)

it tells me that the arguments "start" and "step" are not expected.

code:

```
l = type<bytes>
mylist = [l[i:i+10240] for i in range(start = 0,stop = len(l),step = 10240)]
```

Comment: who? why? what? ... [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you got that message. `range` does not take keyword arguments, and the error is explicit about that:

```
>>> range(start=1, stop=3, step=2)
TypeError: range() does not take keyword arguments
```

Just use positional arguments:

```
range(0, len(l), 10240)
```

Comment: I did this and the same message appeared

Comment: sorry, it worked. I am working on pycharm and it says that this is an error but when i run the code its working

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in range(4, 10, 2):
     print(i)
```

Where 4 start, where 10 stop where 2 step

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.